# Actionscript physics engine which supports particles attracting eachother

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I'm looking for a physics engine for Actionscript which supports particles attracting eachother. Like in [this example](http://phet.colorado.edu/sims/my-solar-system/my-solar-system.swf).

So not just objects being attracted by the floor like in most engines (eg. APE afaik doesn't support particles attracting eachother)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple to add to the list:

[Fisix Engine](http://www.fisixengine.com/)

[Flade](http://www.cove.org/flade/) - I don't know if it has the attractor portion but it's still pretty cool.  :)

Comment: Thanks, the Magnets in Fisix seem to be able to do what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Hype framework](http://hype.joshuadavis.com/). There's loads of attractor, particles, followers, et al. I think you may find something you like regardless ;)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't find that one when I was looking on Google but unfortunately I couldn't find what I needed in there.

Answer (score 0):

The 2 most famous physics engines for flash are:

1. box2d (http://box2dflash.sourceforge.net/)
2. Nape (http://napephys.com/)

make sure to check them out.